# What are the practical uses of the new methods ES5 provides?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

With libraries such as [ES5-Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), we can use the new hotness now. Many methods on arrays (like `forEach`, `map`, `every`, etc) could be used **now** to write clean and beautiful code.

I'd like to have a list a practical uses I can have **right now** with those new methods when working with the current browsers' API (such as the DOM) or with just javascript.

I'm talking about this kind:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('class')
[].forEach.call(nodes, callback)
function callback(node) {
    console.log(node)
}
```

Another example from [@Esailija](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3186672#3186672):

```
[].filter.call( document.myform.elements, function(input){
    return input.type == "text";
});
```

This is the kind of practical use I'm looking for. Some kind of patterns I'd be able to use in real projects.

Comment: Dude, where are your semi-colons? `:P`

Comment: [vector programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) and a more declarative syntax are afforded by the ES5 functions. I'd recommend reading through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas i burned them, burned them all

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I don't like them! The ASI can do a pretty good job, and my code remains pretty clean. But that's not the matter of this question :)

Comment: @zzzzBov: I'm just looking for real examples, not theory.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Are you asking specifically about the ES5 array iteration methods? There is lots of other new API in ES5...

Comment: Not just iterations, everything new in ES5 that just isn't available in any tutorial since it's new, so nobody really uses them.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine The best lecture about the new ES5 APIs is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you really will be able to use is the bind() method, I think.

```
var o = {
    act: function() { ...}
}
// Instead of
element.addEventListener("type", function(){ o.act(); }, false)
// you can write
element.addEventListener("type", o.act.bind(o), false)
```

which is very useful in namespaced modules, where `this` is everything.

The array iterator methods are useful everywhery when it comes to data handling. No specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterator functions to manipulate lists.

So before you used for or while loops and now you use functions.

```
function isTextNode(node) {
    return node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
}

function extractText(node) {
    return node.data
}

function combineText(memo, text) {
    return memo += text
}

var text = toArray(nodeList).filter(isTextNode).map(extractText).reduce(combineText)
```

To get used to "how or why this is useful" stop using for/while and think of your data as sets or lists and think about how you would filter / map / reduce these lists to extract data.

Also make an exercise to not use closures and have your iterator functions seperate and not bound over upvalues.